# Xubuntu 14.04 disables video output when disconneting / reconnecting a HDMI monitor

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, video, hdmi, output

On Xubuntu 13.10 when I disconnect a screen connected on the HDMI output of my computer and then reconnect it, the signal directly comes back to the screen and I can continue to work.

On Xubuntu 14.04 LTS when I disconnect the screen and connect it back, the signal doesn't come back to the screen. I have to reboot the computer to get the signal back.

To try to solve this I've tried to connect a second screen to the other hdmi output to see what's going on when I disconnect the first screen : I can see that xubuntu has actualy disabled the first output and I have to check the box "USE THIS OUTPUT" in the first monitor settings to activate the output.

I was wondering how I can tell to Xubuntu to keep the ouput on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and below is the solution I came up with. It seems after reconnecting the HDMI cable it doesn't enable that output automatically. The solution I found is to run the following command after reconnecting the HDMI cable:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto
```

On my desktop the name of the output is `HDMI1`. To discover the correct name in your machine, run `xrandr` when the monitor is connected and functioning correctly. It will list your outputs and show the name of the connected output.

You can map the command to a keyboard shortcut using XFCE Application Shortcuts found in the settings manager or you can use a program like xbindkeys which does the same thing. That way you reconnect the cable and press a keyboard shortcut to get everything working.

Comment: Thanks Marwan. I've arrived at the same conclusion on my side. It would be great to be able to detect the event of connection of a screen to trigger this command. I've noticed that Xorg.0.log actually changes as soon a screen is connected or disconnect maybe this could be a way.... Definitively it missed a kind of feature in XFCE to tell what is the default operation when a screen connection occurs.